# Zend Framework and PHPBB Integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpbb

The task I am trying to do is to integrate PHPBB with our existing Zend Framework-based web portal. Right now, the registration works by auto-creating accounts both on the framework and PHPBB once a user registers. This feature already works. The next task is to make the user login and logout process simultaneous on both parts. This would mean that I have to have access to Zend's session from inside PHPBB. Once I get this done, everything else will come to light. Right now I'm totally stucked coz the $_SESSION variable is not accessible.

Can anybody point me how to accomplish this? A huge thanks to everyone in advanced.

Comment: The $_SESSION is accessible, why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Really? Sorry about that. I'll check it out and get back with the results in a few.

Comment: Hello again and thanks for the reply. Starting somewhere around line 24, directly after session_begin() I did a print_r($_SESSION) and got the "[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /index.php on line 26: Undefined variable: _SESSION". Any idea?

Comment: session_begin() is not PHP, it's a phpBB thing, I don't know how it sessions are implemented in phpBB but you will have to look into that! Look at the session_begin() function for a start. The PHP equivalent is session_start().

Comment: Yeah, session_begin() is a method of PHPBB's session handler. The problem, I think, lies with how CodeIgniter "hides" PHP's session data for security measures. I'll try to figure out another workaround on this if this approach fails.

Comment: How does Codeigniter come into the equation? In general I think phpBB most probably gives you a public API which you can use to work with its session. Stuff like `$this->phpbb_library->this->_user->data[‘username’]`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Zend Framework, not Codeigniter. What am I saying?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is quite impossible, one of the few solutions that work is to explicitly save the values of the session to a table. Other solutions of course is possible.